# how can I add a prefix on my id field in sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I had tried to define my id field as string and initialAutoIncrement field as 'E-100'. I am using MySQL.

Comment: You can create alphanumeric keys what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: how can I use alphanumeric in id field? can u please show me a demo or link? my id field is not incrementing and saving like E-100null